# How to calculate PSNR and SSIM of SIDD Benchmark,

Tags: python

I would like to ask everyone, I have downloaded the SIDD Benchmark Noisy data set, and then used my denoising model to remove the noise. How do I check the PSNR and SSIM results of my denoising? Where can I find SIDD Benchmark GT? Let me calculate, or get the score through other methods? Thank you.
I don't know how to calculate PSNR and SSIM of SIDD Benchmark.

Comment: Have you tried scikit-image package? SSIM: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_ssim.html and PSNR: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.metrics.html#skimage.metrics.peak_signal_noise_ratio.

Comment: but I cannot find the SIDD Benchmark dataset groundtruth. where could i find them?